# Optimization of system of equations with descriptive statistics functions

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, optimization

Let's say that I have to optimize the following systems of equations and inequalities:

Being $L$ the length variable, $S$ the speed, $TotalTime$ the variable to optimize, and $C$ and $D$ given constants

$$
L = \{ L_0 L_1 ... L_n\} \\ 
S_0L_0 + S_1L_1 ... S_nL_n = TotalTime   \\
L_0 + L_1 + ... + L_n = C \\
Var(L) \leq D
$$

I wonder how should I approach a solution for this problem? Machine learning or reinforcing learning comes to my mind but still I wonder what would be the algebraic way to optimize this problem.

Comment: just set all $L$ to $C/n$, $S_0 = TotalTime/L_0$, $S_i=0$ for $i>1$?

Comment: I forgot to mention that $S = \{ S_0 S_1 ...  S_n \} $ are all constant.

Comment: In that case this is a convex optimization problem (it is even a conic optimization problem). Readily solved with YALMIP or CVX.

Comment: @LinAlg I understand, if you could give some example of how to solve similar problem as an answer I would have a better picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample solution for YALMIP

```
n = 10;
S = rand(n,1);
C = rand(1,1);
D = rand(1,1);

L = sdpvar(n,1);

totaltime = S'*L;
F = [sum(L) == C; (L-mean(L))'*(L-mean(L)) <= D; L >= 0];

optimize(F,totaltime)
```